# NGINX returns 404 even using proxy_pass

Tags: angular, nginx, proxy

I have one NGINX server (nginx1) that should proxy all requests to NGINX server (nginx2) running Angular2 app. Only requests to /api should be sent to a asp.net core server (nginx3). Follow the nginx1 configuration below:

```
 server { # should proxy all requests to nginx2 and /api to nginx3
    listen 80;
    server_name  mywebsite.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://mywebsite.com:4999/;
    }
    # proxy para o backend
    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://mywebsite.com:5001;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }
```

Follow the nginx2 configuration below:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
   include       mime.types;
   default_type  application/octet-stream;
   sendfile        on;
   keepalive_timeout  65;
   server {
       listen       4999;
       server_name  'mywebsite.com';
       location / {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/html; 
           try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ index.html;
       }
       #error_page  404              /error.html;
       # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
       error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
       location = /50x.html {
           root   html;
       }
   }
}
```

If I attempt to open mywebsite.com, it opens correctly, but If I type the complete angular2 route (ex: http://mywebsite.com/orders), I get error 404 from nginx1.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is with your proxy, it is with your NGINX2. On this server, the folder /orders doesn't exist and will return a 404 to the proxy NGINX1 - which will just return that to the caller. In order for this to work, you'd have to add rewrite rules to NGINX2 that rewrites everthing that is not a file or a folder to your main angular2 index.html file.

Comment: Hi Mike, I just added the nginx2 configuration to this post. nginx2 contains the line try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ index.html;

Comment: Okay, should be okay. The only strange thing I see is your default_type  application/octet-stream;

Comment: I removed the line 'default_type  application/octet-stream;'. Nothing changed. Not working. :-(

Comment: If you visit NGINX2 directly (on port 4999) - with path /orders - does it give the 404? Because that would (maybe) rule out the proxy_pass

Comment: Also, is index.html set as your index file? (in http block: index                           index.html;)

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the comments. I just posted an answer. It seems to be related to angular 2 router.

Comment: That really isn't an answer , but a workaround :-) But fine if that is acceptable for you!

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be related to Angular2 router. 
I added the following lines to my app.module.ts (running under nginx2):

```
import {HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from "@angular/common";

    providers: [
            {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy  },
            ...
    ]
```

Now, it works perfectly whenever I type a complete url like http://mywebsite.com/#/orders or refresh any page.

I still think this is not the best solution, since every path now is prefixed with '#', but at least it works. :-)

More info about angular2 HashLocationStrategy at: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html